# How to edit current record and previous record in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table data: -
[image]

I need to be able to identify a bad record by it being minus (< 0) in the StatusDuration.
Then update this record to say set starttime = endtime, StatusDuration = 0.

I then need to edit the previous record by setting endtime = endtime of the current record, StatusDuration = StatusDuration + current StatusDuration.

So I would end up with
[image]

Is this possible in SQL server?

Thanks.

Comment: _previous_ - according to what?

Comment: primary key is record id, which I have missed off, sorry.
This would be record 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
update t
    set endtime = startime,
        statusduration = 0
    where endtime < startime;
```